# Fetch API call fails in react native android for self signed certificate

Tags: react-native

We've used javascript fetch API to connect to server which has self signed certificate, not issued by a trusted CA.

The scenario is that the user gets an option to enter custom server URL that will be changing based upon different customers(enterprises) as we've configured different servers for different customers in their infrastructure for our B2B Android App.

I did a lot of research but didn't find a way in react native android to trust them programmatically in javascript or native module.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm facing with the same problem.